# File Size Limit reached in PhpMyAdmin with 34KB file

Tags: php, mysql, file, phpmyadmin, size

I looked for people with a similar error but I didn't find anyone.
Basically, I want to import data from my database into a database on a test server, both fully running with PhpMyAdmin.
I have exported my data from the full database and then tried importing it on the test server, however I get a file size error:

```
No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or    the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration.
```

The file however has a size of 34 KB, so that error completely mystifies me.
Any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following:
All configurations in my `php.ini` were correct, and I had no `upload_tmp_dir` specified.
However, phpymadmin had its own custom temporary upload folder, located at /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
This was set to `drwxr` (read, write, execute), however it didn't belong to my user, so I did a `chown username tmp`, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini file for configuration.

```
upload_max_filesize = 3M

post_max_size = 3M
```

**OR**

Set custom directory to `upload_tmp_dir` in your php.ini. The directory you set must be writable.

```
upload_tmp_dir = PATH\To\YOURDIRECTORY
```

And don't forget to restart you server.

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 2M, post_max_size = 8M

Comment: The second answer didn't help either, sorry.

Comment: Is your test server on linux or window ?

Comment: It's running on Linux.

Comment: Are you sure the owner of your `upload_tmp_dir` is `chown apache.apache` and permission is `chmod 600` ??

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks for your help! It was actually phpmyadmin's upload folder.